# REPETIR NUMEROS DE 4 EM 4 VEZES EM PHP

Tags: php, for

Olá, desculpa pela ignorância é que eu estou entrando agora no back-end e preciso de um 'for' que repita o mesmo número de 4 em 4, a cada uma repetição ele incrementa, recebe mais um POR EXEMPLO:

DEVE IMPRIMIR ASSIM:

**111222333444555666777...**

Eis o codigo que nao esta dando certo:

```
    $x=0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 28; $i++) {
        if($x<=4){
        $x++;
        echo $x;

    }else{
       $x=0;
       $i=$i-1;  
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 28; $i++) {
    echo "$i$i$i";
}
```

Assim?

Comment: Qual o valor de `$x`? Esse código não vai compilar. Creio que você queria usar `$i` no lugar de `$x`.